# Is it neccessarily the case that $f$ is measurable, if it's measurable in each variable?

Tags: measure-theory

A well-known example of a function that is continuous in each variable but fails to be jointly continuous is:

$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2} & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y) = (0,0) \\
   \end{cases}
$$
**Question$1$:** Is this function "jointly" measurable?

It seems to me it suffices to ask whether the preimage of each element in the $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ is measurable. Thus it reduces to whether $f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is measurable and it is(union of a Borel set and a singleton, or the relative complement of a singleton with respect to a Borel set).

**Question$2$**: Given $f :  X \times Y \to Z$. For each $x_0 \in X$, $f(x_0,\cdot): Y \to Z$ is a measurable function, and for each $y_0 \in Y$, $f(\cdot, y_0): X \to Z$ is also a measurable function. Is it neccessarily the case that $f$ is measurable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two questions are mainly unrelated. The answer to Question 1 is yes, as you showed yourself in the post. The answer to Question 2 is no: consider $X=Y=Z=\mathbb R$ endowed with Borel sigma-algebras and $f$ such that $f(x,y)=1$ if $x=y$ and $x\in A$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise, where $A\subset\mathbb R$ is not measurable.

Then every $f(x,\ )$ and $f(\ ,y)$ is either identically zero or identically zero except at one point hence it is measurable, while $f^{-1}(\{1\})=\{(x,x)\mid x\in A\}$ is not measurable.

Comment: Dear sir, thanks. Allow me to explain why I related the first question to the second. I came up with the second question at first, and I recalled that continuity implies measurability. So a candidate of counterexample that occured to me is the function in question one. In retrospect, it's fair to say they're unrelated.

Comment: Dear sir, sorry for my interruption. I can't understand why $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is not measurable. $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is the subset of $\Delta = \{(x,x): x \in \Bbb R\}$. But $\Delta$ can be covered by countable identical boxes with arbitarily shorter sides. It seems to me $m(f^{-1}[\{1\}]) \leq m(\Delta)=0$.

Comment: You could try to show that for every $B\subseteq\mathbb R$, $\{(x,x)\mid x\in B\}$ is measurable if and only if $B$ is measurable.

Comment: I think the confusions stems from the function in the example being Lebesgue measurable but not Borel measurable.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: Thank you. That's something subtle for me.